# CED-MIS Web Service details

Tags: database

i don't know about "CED-MIS" web Service Could You Please Help Me To About This Services I have Zero Knowledge about this PLease help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions to use from Web Service :

- DownloadTraineesData

  http://117.247.80.146/CEDBiometricServiceApp/Services/CEDStudentData.svc/DownloadTraineesData?TPID=36&UserName=demo&Password=demo
- UploadTraineesAttendanceData [JSON]

http://117.247.80.146/CEDBiometricServiceApp/Services/CEDStudentData.svc/
UploadTraineesAttendanceData?token=[{"TrainingPartnerID":36,"BatchID":1,"TrainingPartnerName":null,"BatchName":"anchor umesh","UserName":"demo","Password":"demo","PunchDate":"2015-05-03","PunchTime":"10:10:10","Field1":null,"Field2":null,"CreateUserID":0, "BatchNo":"12014-2015/anchorumesh/B","Courseid":152,"CourseName":"Instrument Attendant Chemical Plant","TraineeID":1,"TraineeName":"Umesh A
        Luhar","EnrollmentNo":null}]